# Как посмотреть результат проверки правки метки?

Tags: поддержка, метки, правки

Сделал правку метки, новое полное описание было принято, а короткое нет, и я бы хотел посмотреть фидбек проверяющих, но уже нигде не могу найти.

После предложения нового описания метки, правка попадает в очередь на ревью. Пока проверка идёт, в описании метки отображается твоя версия и ссылка на ревью, и если успеть ткнуть по ней, то можно будет смотреть комментарии проверяющих. Однако если не успеть, то ссылка пропадает - как тогда найти эту ссылку с полезным фидбеком?

Comment: *а короткое нет* — скорее всего, причина: «нет руководства по использованию метки».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Профиль -> Активность -> Все действия -> Предложенные правки.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: у меня в этом списке последняя запись — от 2016 года. а последняя предложенная правка — [в этом месяце](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/483087/revisions). это баг или фича?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, предложенные правки - это когда у тебя репутации меньше 2К и они отправляются в очередь проверок.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, для меток по идее должно работать, но по твоей ссылке твоя правка - просто правка, а вот у αλεχολυτ предложенная.

Comment: не знал, что описание меток можно править без премодерации, не имея при этом какого-то приличного количества репутации по данной метке (что требуется, например, для создания синонимов меток). спасибо.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, видимо, как-то по-другому работает... Надо где-то поискать...

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вот что-то по теме: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341934/309650.